# Song title encoding in audio stream

Tags: audio, streaming, mp3

Can anyone point me in the right direction for documentation regarding how the song title text is encoded in streaming audio? (for instance streaming mp3 - both other formats/protocols would also be useful). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to use [ID3v2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) for streaming audio.

ID3 is the standard way to embed meta data in mp3

[This is how shoutcast does it](http://smackfu.com/stuff/programming/shoutcast.html)

Comment: Perhaps, but ID3 is usually at the start of an mp3 file - so how can a player read it from a stream that is already halfway through a song? Plus the meta info available in a stream is usually tiny compared to the swathe of info in ID3 tags.

Comment: It looks like it varies.  Where are you streaming from?  This is how shoutcast does it - http://www.smackfu.com/stuff/programming/shoutcast.html

Comment: That's a great link thanks.  I'm trying to get a picture for the most common methods.  Looks like they insert the song title at fixed intervals in the stream in this case, which makes sense.  Hope you don't mind if I insert this in your answer so I can vote up...

Answer (score 1):

You should also look at [Real Time Streaming Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol), which can request metadata in [Session Description Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Description_Protocol) format that includes the media title and other pertinent information.

AFAIK, Windows Media Streaming and the Apple Quicktime streaming server use this.